# Extract date-by-date values also when no data

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce

I have this table

```
records
- id
- date
- typology
```

I want to extract a day-by-day count of records with typology = 999. I know there's at least 1 record for each day, but most of days I don't have a record with typology 999.

I tried something like

```
select count(*) from records where typology = 999 and date > '2017-01-01' group by date order by date asc;
```

hoping to get something like

```
285 | 2017-01-06 |
307 | 2017-01-07 |
  0 | 2017-01-08 |
316 | 2017-01-09 |
```

but I don't. I get

```
285 | 2017-01-06 |
307 | 2017-01-07 |
316 | 2017-01-09 |
```

and that's right. Since there are no records with typology 999 on the 8th of january, I don't get that line. But I'd like to. I don't have to "invent" the 2017-01-08 date, there are for sure records with that date (but different typologies).

I tried a bit with coalesce and subqueries but coudn't get much out of it, mostly because I have two fields and coalesce seems to me to work fine just with one.

I tried with a CASE as well

```
SELECT CASE c WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE c END
FROM (
select count(*) as c from records where typology = 892 and date > '2017-01-01' group by date order by date asc
) as s;
```

didn't work either. I'm pretty sure it's quite a messed-up query.

Do you happen to have any suggestion for me?

Thank you
Marco

Comment: `Calendar table + Left Join + count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t.date,
  count(r.date)
from records r
right join
  ( select date from records where date > '2017-01-01' group by date
  ) t
on r.date      = t.date
and r.typology = 999
group by t.date
order by t.date asc;
```

Comment: Thank you, editing your solution I managed to find what I was looking for. This is the final query I used: select t.dateField,
count(*)
from records r right join
 ( select DATE(date) as dateField
 from records
 where date > '2016-12-01'
 group by DATE(date)) t
on DATE(r.date) = t.dateField
and r.typology = 999
group by t.dateField order by t.dateField asc;

Comment: I changed the first count(date) to count(*) because I got 1 also where the number of records was 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) to generate all the dates between specified start and end. Then `left join` on this to get `0` counts for missing dates.

```
select d.dt,coalesce(r.cnt,0) as cnt    
from (select * 
      from generate_series('2017-01-02'::date,'2017-12-31'::date,'1 day') as dt) d
     --change the start and end date,interval in generate_series as required
left join (select date,count(*) as cnt
           from records 
           where typology = 892 and date > '2017-01-01'
           group by date) r
on r.date=d.dt
```

Comment: It probably works but I liked the other solution better since it doesn't use coalesce and generate_series. This is interesting though. Thank you!